# ng serve is not building the browser

Tags: angular

97 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

63 vulnerabilities (1 low, 15 moderate, 39 high, 8 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

```
C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old>ng serve
- Generating browser application bundles...(node:15136) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
\ Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\util\createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:452:10       
    at C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:323:13       
    at C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11 
    at C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:203:19 
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\virtual_file_system_decorator.js:48:13)
    at processResource (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:202:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:158:10)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at C:\Users\vkethe\edm020123\edm-dxc-web-ui-old\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14 {      
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

when we run ng serve the browser have to build